# Dynamically switch ItemProcessor based on JobParameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Following is the code sample of a reader bean

```
<bean id="reader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
        scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql"
        value="#{@sqlStatements[jobParameters['key']]}" />
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="#{jobParameters['key'] + 'Mapper'}" />
</bean>
```

There is `<util:map id="sqlStatements"/>`. I have a similar bean for writer. I want to have a dynamic switcher for processor. The interface `ItemProcessor<I,O>` needs `I` & `O` to be mentioned, either I must switch it in some way or create a custom ItemProcessor.

I tried the below code but it didn't work.

```
<batch:job id="springBatch">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="reader" processor="#{jobParameters['key'] + 'Processor'}"
                writer="writer" commit-interval="1"></batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

It gave a `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException` for jobParameters, probably because `scope=step` was not defined for it.

Could someone please provide an alternative for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a [`Classifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/classify/class-use/Classifier.html) can simplify a lot resolution of this problem: create a custom `ItemProcessor<Object, Object>` and inject a `Classifier<Class, ItemProcessor>` (a [`PatternMatchingClassifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/classify/PatternMatchingClassifier.html) can fits) and in `ItemProcessor.process()` detect right processor using classifier.
Also look at [`ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html#setClassifier%28org.springframework.classify.Classifier%29).

Comment: Such an ItemProcessor is provided by the framework as of 3.0: [ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow your question completely but one simple solution can be creating a custom processor as delegator. This delegator will delegate processor code to relevant Item Processor class based on job parameters key or whatever logic you want.